# how do i make an object with defaults without setting them one by one?

Tags: typescript, types, default

I'm trying to make a type that sets defaults along creating any type 
the types:

```js
// main type used to set default on a property/key
type Default<Q> = [Q];
// extract defaults into a type
type Defaults<G> = Extract<G, object> extends never
  ? undefined
  : {
      // gather non default keys and set them to undefined
      [K in keyof G as Extract<G[K], Default<G[K]>> extends never
        ? K
        : never]: Defaults<Exclude<G[K], any[]>>;
    } & {
      // gather default keys values
      [K in keyof G as Extract<G[K], Default<G[K]>> extends never
        ? never
        : K]: Extract<G[K], Default<G[K]>> extends [infer A] ? A : never;
    } extends infer G
  ? { [K in keyof G]?: G[K] }
  : never;
// extract property/key main type without Default<Q>
type NonDefaults<F> = Extract<F, object> extends never
  ? F
  : { [K in keyof F]: NonDefaults<Exclude<F[K], Default<F[K]>>> };
```

usage example:

```js
type Test = {
  id: string;
  way?: string | string[] | Default<"up">;
  isUp?: boolean | Default<true>;
  deep?: {
    hello: string;
    world?: string | Default<"#world">;
    deeper: {
      make: boolean | Default<true>;
    };
  };
};
type TestDefaults = Defaults<Test>;
type TestTypes = NonDefaults<Test>;
```

now, what i want to happen is to create a property with defaults values set:

```js
function mergeDefaults(config: Test) {
 const defaults: TestDefaults = {}
 console.log(defaults) // here i want to see defaults as values instead of types
 // then i would merge config with defaults and return it
 return config as TestTypes
}
function useTest(config: Test) {
 config = mergeDefaults(config)
}
```

any help, guidance or suggestions is much appreciated :)

PS:my goal by doing this is to reduce number of objects created that are used to only set default values, also, to keep docs in the same place as the type defaults. so everything is in one place (defaults, docs and types) and the only difference is how they're used.

Comment: That is not possible with TypeScript alone. All the type information of `Test` or `TestDefaults` is erased and not accessible during runtime. So you can't create an object with default values based on a type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single object containing all the default field values and put it in the prototype chain of all the objects that should have those defaults. With this approach, deleting a field value on the inheriting object will make accesses of that field on that object resolve back to the default from the prototype again.

- You can set the prototype of an object after it is created using [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)
- If you can, it is better to set the prototype at the time of creating an object. You can do this with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [See MDN for more information about prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)